# How can I get away with an intransitive comparator?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparison, comparator

I have a `Comparator<Foo>` with the following comparison function:

```
float d = o1.bar - o2.bar;
if (Math.abs(d) <= 0.001) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return d < 0 ? -1 : 1; // inline Math.copySign
}
```

Essentially, this is supposed to compare two `Foo`s based on their `bar` property unless the values are close enough, in which case they should be declared equal. (This is important because I'm doing another sort after this, on a different property.)

Obviously, though, this is not a transitive comparator. If there are `Foo`s `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` with values of `bar` as `1.999`, `2.000`, and `2.001`, respectively, then, according to my comparator, `f1==f2` and `f2==f3`  but `f1 != f3`.

Calling `sort(myListOfFoo, myFooComparator)` gives a "Comparison method violates its general contract!" error very rarely, but deterministically.

How can I use such a comparator with `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` without generating this error?

---

Alternatively, is there some way I can store my data that will allow the comparator to work properly? Roudning each float to the nearest `0.001` at construction would be the simplest solution, except that the `Foo.bar` field is actually calculated based on an arbitrary distance metric, so it's not that simple.

The actual code is:

```
float d = metric.distance(vertex, o1)
        - metric.distance(vertex, o2);
if (Math.abs(d) < threshold) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return d < 0 ? -1 : 1; // inline Math.copySign
}
```

where `o1`, `o2`, and `vertex` are instances of `class Point { float x; float y; }` and `metric` is an instance of `interface DistanceMetric { float distance(Point p1, Point p2); }`. It may be worth noting that this is failing even on the standard Euclidean metric.

Comment: your solution won't work also. Supose threshold = 0.5 : 2.1 gets rounded to 2.0, 2.4 gets rounded to 2.5. Following your rule they should be equal, but now 2.1 is smaller than 2.4. Same applies for ceil or floor.

Comment: @Cristopher Thanks. That's true, and a good point. But the main reason it won't work is still because the values are non-constant.

Comment: What is the point of the threshold if you just want to `sort` the `Point`s ? Do you need to remove the points at the same distance, or something like that ? Because, otherwise, you can just use a "normal" sort based on the distance, and all the points at the "same" distance will be sorted correctly, and will be one after another in the sorted list.

Comment: Accept that it's okay that minute differences below 0.01 or whatever are reflected in the sort order, and just sort normally.

Comment: If you're doing another sort after this, seems like it would be **less** important for this sort to be stable, not more. Did you mean you had previously sorted on another property? Perhaps I'm not understanding your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that the Java 7 sort implementation will not tolerate a Comparator that exhibits intransitivity.  There is nothing you can do about that ... if you want to use the standard Java SE sorting APIs.

---

But, in fact, using threshold comparison in a sort is actually mathematically incorrect.

The issues when comparing floating point values are that they are often imprecise to start with, and the calculations then *typically* introduce further small errors into the results.  When two results are close enough, the accumulated error may larger than the difference between the values ... meaning that we can't tell whether the ideal numbers (without the errors) are less, equal or greater than each error.  We deal with this by treating "close to equals" as being "equal", by comparing using a threshold.

When we are sorting values (i.e. placing them in order), the issue of errors in the values needs to be handled differently.  Suppose that

- we have two numbers `v1 ± e1` and `v2 ± e2`, and
- when we compare the numbers using threshold comparison, the threshold is greater than `mod(e1) + mod(e2)`

If it turns out that `v1` and `v2` are close enough that `mod(v1 - v2) < (mod(e1) + mod(e2))` then *it doesn't matter* if we put `v1 ± e1` before or after `v2 ± e2` in the ordering.  If we *observe* the ordering of the two numbers (after the sort has completed) by comparing using the threshold, they will show as "equal", which ever order we put them in.

So if we ignored errors and simply ordered the numbers using precise comparisons, we won't put any pair of numbers in an *incorrect* order as far as we can discern when we use threshold-based comparison.

Now suppose that we have `v1 ± e1`, `v2 ± e2` and `v3 ± e3` ... and 
`mod(e1) + mod(e3)` is GREATER that our threshold:

- If we order as above (using precise comparison) we will still end up with the numbers in the right order.
- If we used "comparison with thresholds" to order the values (and the sort implementation allowed that!), we could end up with the numbers in the order `v3 ± e3`, `v2 ± e2` and `v1 ± e1`.  We have `{v1 ± e1, v2 ± e2}` and `{v2 ± e2, v3 ± e3}` are pairwise equal, but we could also have `{v1 ± e3, v3 ± e3}` incorrectly ordered, even when we compare using threshold-based comparisons!

---

The bottom line is that you *should* simply implement your `Comparator` (for sorting purposes!) to use exact comparisons.  Threshold comparison is wrong for this context.  This applies irrespective of how the `sort` algorithm is coded ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you actually want to do is remove duplicate values ( by your threshold ) and then sort the rest. Why don't you do a natural sorting first based on non-rounded values, and then use filtering based on your threshold value.