# Merge n lists and sort data maintaining original order/constraint

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge, comparator

I encountered the below problem in a coding competition. I tried a lot but a private test case was always failing for me with wrong answer and I am unable to figure out why my below approach would fail. I've no naive solution to generate stress test cases and compare. Also, there will be no editorial published. 
So, I am looking for someone to point out the flaw in my approach if possible.

Following is a detailed description of the problem and what I've tried till now.

Problem:
There are multiple regions and you are given marks for students for each region as per their rank in the respective region.
For example:

```
Region1:
StudentName, Score
A,           50.0
B,           60.0  
C,           40.0 

Region2:
StudentName, Score
D,           30.0
E,           10.0
F,           20.0
```

In the above data, Student A has rank 1 in Region1, B has Rank2 in Region1 and C has Rank3 in Region1.
Similarly, D has Rank1 in Region2, E has Rank2 and F has Rank3.

- A student could have lesser score and still have a greater rank within the same region. For example, A has better rank than B in Region1 i.e. we should assume that each region's data is already sorted according to ranks.

Our task is to merge all region's data and create a global data ranked according to score. The constraint is that any student who was at a lower rank in the region still cannot have a rank above the other students from it's region having a better rank than it in the original region data.

For example:

```
Region1:
A, 50.0
B, 60.0
C, 40.0 

Region2:
D, 30.0
E, 10.0
F, 20.0
```

will be merged into:

```
A, 50.0
B, 60.0
C, 40.0 
D, 30.0
E, 10.0
F, 20.0
```

The order did not change according to score because B will always be lower than A and F will always be lower than E as per their region's constraints.

Other test cases:

```
Region1:
A, 50.0
B, 60.0
C, 70.0 

Region2:
D, 30.0
E, 20.0
F, 10.0
```

again results in the order of A,B,C,D,E,F

```
Region1:
A, 60.0
B, 80.0
C, 100.0 

Region2:
D, 70.0
E, 90.0
F, 110.0
```

will result in:
D, E, F, A, B, C

But,

```
Region1:
A, 11.5
B, 8.5
C, 10.0 

Region2:
D, 12.0
E, 9.0
F, 9.5
```

will result in:

```
D, 12.0
A, 11.5
E, 9.0 
B, 8.5
C, 10.0
F, 9.5

Constraints:
1<=number of regions<=6
score can be upto 7 decimal places
```

My approach is to add all the input data to one list and maintain a stable sort i.e. if the zone is same for two students, compare their rank in the zone, otherwise compare scores.

```
static class Student implements Comparable<Student>
{
String name;
double score;
int zone;
int rank;

//constructor

public int compareTo(Student o)
{
if(this.zone == o.zone)
{
//lower i.e. better rank
return Integer.compare(this.rank, o.rank);
}
//higher i.e. better score
return Double.compare(o.score, this.score);
}

}

main()
{
//read data from console input into an ArrayList<Student> students
Collections.sort(students);
//print each student from students

}
```

The question does not mention if score could be equal for two students in different zones. I've tried breaking the tie in that case using their respective ranks in the zone but the private test cases keep failing. I initially thought that the question might have some missing information but I see many successful submissions for this question in the competition dashboard. This is the reason I believe I am missing something and the question is not as simple as I am thinking. But, I've not been able to come up with a test case to validate this assumption.

Thanks!

Comment: sorry, there is no public link

Comment: @ruakh The problem makes sense but it is confusing; I had to read it a couple times before I understood it. However, what’s not clear to me is whether the imposition of partial orderings within regions results in a unique result for the merged list. In other words the constraints described here might not impose a total ordering.

Comment: I provided such detailed problem description, test cases, my approach and all other things but still got downvote :( Nothing can help you escape the pessimism here sometimes

Comment: @StuartMarks what do you mean by  "unique result" in your comment?

Comment: Ideally if one applies all the constraints there will be exactly one result list that can satisfy those constraints. But it appears that the constraints as described can be satisfied by several different results. Either the problem is underconstrained, or your description inadvertently omitted some details, or I’m misunderstanding something.

Comment: Consider the last example. It appears to me that the following two examples satisfy all the constraints: (1) `D=12.0 A=11.5 B=8.5 C=10.0 E=9.0 F=9.5` and (2) `D=12.0 A=11.5 E=9.0 F=9.5 B=8.5 C=10.0`. There are also several other examples. What criteria would one use to choose one of these over the other(s)?

Comment: the main issue is that if you compare by rank for the region, then by score, then your sort is not valid. If you have `A: { Score: 50, Region: 1, Rank: 1}, B: {Score: 10, Region: 2, Rank: 1}, C: { Score: 100, Region: 2, Rank: 2}`, then your sort cannot say if A goes first (order A, B, C, 50 > 10), or last (order B, C, A, 100 > 50). You need a way to let C know that it's _effective score_ against other regions is actually 10, since it's below B.

Comment: @ruakh what do you think is wrong with that example? The sorting/global rank is constrained due to element's respective positions in the region

Comment: @njzk2 i'm not comparing by rank first and then by score. I compare by rank only if they belong to the same region/zone to maintain the original order of appearance,  otherwise always by score

Comment: @ruakh sorry, updated that test case. Does it look good to you now?

Comment: @Stacky that's what I meant. In the example I gave, A > B, B > C, C > A. Your ordering relation is not transitive, meaning you can't use it to sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question, the requirements are to sort the students according to score, but with the additional constraint that the relative ordering of students within a region be preserved.

Given the input data from one of the examples listed in the question,

```
Region1:
A, 11.5
B, 8.5
C, 10.0 

Region2:
D, 12.0
E, 9.0
F, 9.5
```

sorting only by score gives the following result: DACFEB.

However, the constraint about preserving relative ordering within a region requires the following *partial orderings* A < B < C and D < E < F.

The OP gives the solution to this particular example as DAEBCF. In comments on the question, I suggested two other possible solutions for this example: DABCEF and DAEFBC. I don't see any criteria which let us decide which of these possible solutions is the correct one. As such, the problem is underconstrained. One can argue about which of these solutions is preferable to the others, but doing so will introduce new constraints which aren't in evidence in the original question.

Given that there are multiple solutions that meet all the criteria in the problem, it means that there is no *total ordering* of values in this domain. Further, given that a correct Comparator must impose a total ordering on the values of its domain, it follows that it is not possible to write a proper Comparator for this domain.

Of course, it's possible to write a correct Comparator that has some behavior, and that will prefer *one* of these possible solutions over the others. Doing so will implicitly be implementing additional constraints that aren't part of the problem statement. In fact, it appears that [Vincent van der Weele](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54855213/1441122) has done so. The statement "The next empty spot must be filled by the highest ranked remaining element of one of the regions. Which one? The one with the highest score" introduces the additional constraint. It results in the ordering DAEBCF, which was suggested by the OP. While this is sensible, but it's necessarily the "right" ordering.

An alternative algorithm might be as follows. 1) Start with an empty result list and maintain lists of students from each region in rank order. 2) Find the remaining student with the highest score. 3) Take that student, and higher-ranked students within the same region, and append them to the result, preserving relative order. 4) Repeat until no students remain.

Applying this algorithm to the example input results in DABCEF. This is sensible, but in a different way. Again, we don't know whether it's the "right" answer.

Either the problem in the programming competition was ill-specified to begin with, or some information was lost between the competition's problem statement and the OP's question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. "Of course, it's possible to write a correct Comparator that has some behavior, and that will prefer one of these possible solutions over the others." - could you suggest one such comparator? Obviously, the one I wrote fails even on the second last test case. It gives me A,B,C,D,E,F instead of D,E,F,A,B,C. So, it does not satisfy any "ordering".

Comment: @Stacky Both Vincent van der Weele and I have described *algorithms* for producing orderings given various different rules. However, writing *comparators* that impose the equivalent ordering as those algorithms is a bit subtle. It may take some time for me to get to it.

Comment: Stuart Marks, I've been reading about transitivity and as described by you, @njzk2 and others the second last test case shows that my comparator is not transitive. I am wondering why Collections.sort did not throw an exception saying "Comparison method violates its general contract" as described in the following question. I think the exception it is not guaranteed by jvm. I even tried running my comparator on multiple random inputs but no exception was generated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843689/how-can-i-get-away-with-an-intransitive-comparator

Answer (score 1):

Your comparitor is not correct. You basically say that students are sorted by rank if they are from the same region and sorted by score otherwise. But this is not true, as this example shows:

```
Region1:
A, 11.5
B, 8.5
C, 10.0 

Region2:
D, 12.0
E, 9.0
F, 9.5
```

results in

```
D, 12.0
A, 11.5
E, 9.0 
B, 8.5
C, 10.0
F, 9.5
```

i.e., E with score 9.0 comes before C with score 10.0, even though they are from different regions.

---

A simpler algorithm which does work:

Fill the result element by element. The next empty spot must be filled by the highest ranked remaining element of one of the regions. Which one? The one with the highest score. So remove that element from its region, add it to the result, and repeat until you are done.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this test case which I came up with might be the failing one. I'll try your approach. I think the answer to this one should be - 
D, 12.0
A, 11.5
C, 10.0
E, 9.0 
B, 8.5
F, 9.5
Could we achieve this using the comparator? I don't understand why the comparator is failing during the sort when every element is compared to each other in a sort?
The number of input regions could change 1<=n<=6, so I wanted to fill everything and then sort.

Comment: I noticed @ruakh and assumed it was a copy-paste error in the OP because it's not in line with the problem description but I agree one shouldn't make assumptions like that. If that example is correct, my algorithm indeed doesn't work.

Comment: @Stacky, no that would be the answer when using your comparator, which is exactly why it's not correct. You would put C before B, which is not allowed. The problem with the comparator is that it's not transitive: `B > C` (because of rank), `C > E` (because of value) and `E > B` (because of value). When you sort using a comparator like that, the result is either arbitrary or the algorithm will never end, depending on which sort implementation you use.

Comment: @Vincent van der Weele , no actually the comparator is giving the following result which is present in the question description and also quoted in your answer: D, 12.0
A, 11.5
E, 9.0 
B, 8.5
C, 10.0
F, 9.5
I now think that this answer is correct as C cannot be put before B (you also mentioned the same in your above comment) Why do you think it is incorrect and what should the correct answer be?

Comment: When your comparator does not respect transitivity, the outcome of sorting *might* not be correct. That doesn't mean that it's wrong for every input. It's worth noting that if your input consists of two regions, each having the exact same number of students, your algorithm in combination with merge sort is actually the exact same as mine. Try running some examples with more students, more regions, or a different number of students per region. You should see that the outcome becomes wrong in some of those cases.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele I will read more on transitivity of comparators and try to generate a test case which fails, unfortunately I haven't been able to find one yet. Some part of your original answer doesn't seem to be valid now as that test case is correct because C cannot come before B. Would you like to please update it?